# Pull method of underlying source of a ReadableStream (of JS Web API ) , api instruction unclear

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement ReadableStream in a JSEngine (Quickjs). [The web api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/ReadableStream#specifications) for `pull` method of underlying sources says:

> This method **will be called repeatedly** when the stream's internal queue of chunks is not full, up until it reaches its high water mark.

Won't this make the ReadableStream in infinite loop, if pull instead do nothing.
Consider code like this :

```js
let a = new ReadableStream({
    start(c){},pull(c){
        console.log("Hello");
    }
});
```

As per the specification this script should be non terminating loop, as pull will be called repeatedly, to meet the watermark. But when I test this code in chrome, this one prints `Hello` once.
So what is the criteria/specifications than to deal with such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Upon doing a test in chrome console with a code like this:

```js
let i = 0;
let a = new ReadableStream({
    start(c){},pull(c){
        console.log("Hello");
        if(i<3 || i>7){
             c.enqueue("data");   
        }
        i++;
    }
},{highWaterMark:5});
//Hello (prints 5 times)

//this can be used to test further functioning
let r = a.getReader();
r.read().then(e=>{console.log(e)});
```

the conclusion is :
**Loop to call `pull` terminates on two cases, if `highWaterMark` is reached and if the queue size do not changes after an iteration`**

And this call to pull is done at:

1. At the construction of the stream.
2. Whenever a read is done via a reader.